# Provide BeanFactory Bean in TestNg test cases using spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testng, spring-test

I am using TestNg in spring boot for test cases.
One of the object in my test case have dependency of BeanFactory Bean.

```
@Test
void testMe(){
Obj obj = new Obj();
}
```

above is the test case and below is the Obj class

```
class Obj{

@Autowired
BeanFactory beanFactory;
//rest of the code

}
```

when I run above test case it gives me null pointer exception , anybody has idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

To inject/autowire Spring context, you need to load Spring context in Test Class, e.g. [with XML configurations](https://www.mkyong.com/unittest/testng-spring-integration-example/)

> ```
> @Test
> @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:spring-test-config.xml" })
> ```

Also you should Class should extends relevant class, as [AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/testng/AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.html)

> Abstract base test class which integrates the Spring TestContext Framework with explicit ApplicationContext testing support in a TestNG environment.

For [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-testng/src/test/java/sample/testng/SampleTestNGApplicationTests.java):

> ```
> @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
>  public class SampleTestNGApplicationTests extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
> ```

Comment: `@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:spring-test-config.xml" })
public class DabekCostServiceTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {`


I tried your solution but I am getting below error
**Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring-test-config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist**

Comment: @Aviral This is an example, please edit your question with How Spring is configured, and Test should use the configuration accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I have solved by using below code , adding missing dependency in @ContextConfiguration , and running it with @SpringBootTest

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ContextProvider.class, ApplicationContext.class, TraceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class DabekCostServiceTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
```